# Как использовать деструктуризацию?

Tags: node.js

```
app.post('/create',(request, response) => {
  const {title, body} = request.body;
  Post.create({
    title: title,
    body: body
  }).then(post => console.log(post._id))

  response.redirect('/');
});
```

Пишет ошибку при деструктуризации

> const {title, body} = request.body;
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Версия ноды v4.2.6

Comment: в v4 нет destructuring. https://node.green/#ES2015-syntax-destructuring--declarations

Comment: Никак (без обновления ноды)